# ORA-01000: maximum open cursors exceeded

Tags: oracle, delphi, delphi-7

Using Delphi 7, BDE, and Oracle

I perform a SQL select statement and then step through each of the records of the returned set and perform the following update sql

```
var
 AQuery: TQuery;
begin
 AQuery:= TQuery.Create(nil);
 AQuery.DatabaseName:= ADatabase.DatabaseName;
 with AQuery do
 begin
  SQL.Text:= 'UPDATE AP_Master SET CMCL_FORECAST_CLEARED=:AClearedDate WHERE ID=:AMasterId';
  ParamByName('AMasterId').AsString:= IntToStr(AId);
  ParamByName('AClearedDate').AsDateTime:= StrToDateTime(FormatDateTime('mm/dd/yyyy', AForeCastClearedDate));
  try
   ExecSql;
  except on E: Exception do
   begin
    raise Exception.create('Error Updating AP_Master Tables Forecast Cleared Date!' + E.Message);
   end;//except
  end; //try
 end; //with
 AQuery.Close;
 AQuery.Free;
end;
```

It works for the forst 500 + records, but i then get a : ORA-01000: maximum open cursors exceeded message

Is there something i need to do on the BDE side, oracle side, or within my code (Im using standard TQuery and TDatabase components)

Comment: did you read http://mail.dir.bg/~radoslav.rusinov/Blog/How.to.Cope.with.an.ORA-01000.Error-v.2.1.pdf ?

Comment: You should at least put the Close() and Free() in a try/finally block. But I don't expect that this will solve the problem.

Comment: ParamByName('AMasterId').AsString:= IntToStr(AId);  could be simply written as ParamByName('AMasterId').AsInteger:= AId; and probably you can do the same with the date. Why Get a date, convert it to a string, then get that string and turn it into a date? IF you need to get only the day/month/year part there are better ways (i.e. Trunc()).

Comment: @ldsandon: I got the date thing, but missed the IntToStr one. I've corrected my code in my answer to reflect this also. Thx.

Comment: Also, are you connecting through the BDE using the SQL Links or via ODBC? If ODBC the Oracle ODBC or the Microsoft ODBC for Oracle? Versions?

Comment: Do you have any database triggers defined on your AP_MASTER table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your close of the query is out of place, meaning you're orphaning cursors for each row. Try this instead:

```
var
 AQuery: TQuery;
begin
  AQuery:= TQuery.Create(nil);
  try
    AQuery.DatabaseName:= ADatabase.DatabaseName;

    with AQuery do
    begin
      SQL.Text:= 'UPDATE AP_Master'#13 +
                 'SET CMCL_FORECAST_CLEARED = :AClearedDate'#13 +
                 'WHERE ID= :AMasterId';
      ParamByName('AMasterId').AsInteger := AId;
      // Note the date->string->date is not necessary; setting the param
      // AsDateTime with a TDateTime value will format it correctly for you.
      ParamByName('AClearedDate').AsDateTime:= AForeCastClearedDate;

      try // Protect open
        try
          ExecSql;
          except 
           on E: Exception do
             raise Exception.create('Error Updating AP_Master Tables' +
                                    ' Forecast Date Cleared' +
                                    E.Message);   
          end;//except
        end; // except try
      finally
        AQuery.Close;  // finally means it's closed every time always
      end; //finally try for opening
    end; //with
  finally
    AQuery.Free;  // finally here ensures free
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Not true. The code i posted above is a routine.  My loop through the select sql return set, calls the routine for each record. So, if you look at the code i posted above, for each record in the select, that code above is called (or that routine is called). The query is created, its executed, its closed and free'd, and the loop goes to the next record in the select statement and executes the routine (code above).

Comment: Shane, have you tried Ken's answer before post your comment? I believe this is the solution to your question. And by the way, the code after the Except will not execute.

Comment: Then you failed to post the part of the code that showed it was a function/procedure. (Your question failed to mention that as well.) "step through each of the records of the returned set and perform the following update sql" - this looks like a loop to me, and without any other way of knowing that's what my answer was based on.

Comment: You still have the Close/Free calls skipped if an exception is encountered. If you re-raise an exception in an exception handler, it will make code to "jump" to an outer exception handler.
Also if this is a function called for each record of an external loop it is very inefficient, you could create the query once and then just re-execute it changing parameters only. Even better, you may use a single query to perform the update in a whole without cycling client side.

Comment: @Shane Once release all the sessions or restart your pc and then try Ken's solution

Comment: Has the table triggers? How are OPEN_CURSOR and CURSOR_SHARING set? Which version of Oracle (including patch set and patch applied)? See here for some troubleshooting step Oracle-side: http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:685336504294

Comment: An 'update' statement shouldn't require a cursor at all. That's one of the beauties of a set based language. What happens if you run your query via a SQL monitor program (I don't know what that would be for Oracle, but for Firebird there is EMS SQL Manager).

Comment: AFAIK an update will not create a cursor handled to the client, but it could require cursors internally to manager the update itself. It can actually require more than one.

Comment: I get the same message when run within SQL Developer

Comment: What did you run in SQL Developer? Could you please answer the other questions asked you (triggers, settings, etc.)? Oracle is a very complex piece of software - if you want to pin the issue you need to help us, or finding the correct issue is very difficult.

Comment: Turns out it was a code issue, and one found with in a nested set of queries. THanks for all your help and suggestions, i learned alot from all your comments, statements, and answers